# How do I solve Live Mesh instllation error "80072F78. The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response "?

Tags: installation, windows-live-mesh

When I try and install Live Mesh, I get the following error ...

> "Live Mesh Service is unavailable.
>   Please retry your installation later
>   80072F78. The server returned an
>   invalid or unrecognized response ."

I tried installing the work-around from [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/LiveMesh/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=475395), but that did not work either.  I am using Windows 7 RC x64.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with real-time checking from anti-virus software.  I got the clue from [this blog post](http://the-network-guy.blogspot.com/2008/11/live-mesh-service-is-unavailable-error.html).  I had to disable all real-time checking from AVG, reboot and then installation succeeded without problem.